# a bytes-like object is required, not 'Image'

Tags: python

I want to write an Image object to disk but I keep getting the error:

```
 a bytes-like object is required, not 'Image'
```

First I convert a String to an array and then I create an Image using that array.

```
    class Item(object):

def __init__(self, patch, coords, label):

    self.channels = patch.shape[2]
    # Assuming only square images.
    self.size = patch.shape[0]
    self.data = patch.tobytes()
    self.label = label # Integer label ie, 2 = Carcinoma in situ
    self.coords = coords

def get_label_array(self, num_classes):
    l = np.zeros((num_classes))
    l[self.label] = 1
    return l

def get_patch(self):
    return np.fromstring(self.data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(self.size, self.size, self.channels)

def get_patch_as_image(self):
    return Image.fromarray(self.get_patch(), 'RGB')
```

Is there any way that I can save the image using:

```
def save_in_disk(patches, coords, file_name, labels=[]):
    use_label = False
    if len(labels) > 0:
        use_label = True

    # txn is a Transaction object
    for i in range(len(patches)):
        if use_label:
            item = Item(patches[i], coords[i], labels[i])
        else:
            item = Item(patches[i], coords[i], 0)

        p = item.get_patch_as_image()

        str_id = file_name + '-' + str(coords[i][0]) + '-' + str(coords[i][1]) + '.png'
        print(str_id)
        with open(str_id, 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(p)
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Regards

Comment: What library / object are you using, and what do you exactly want ? To write a raw png file to disk, or to save a python object ?

Comment: If you want to save the image as PNG you must use the appropriate routine from your image handling library. The basic file API only allows you to write arrays of bytes, and you can probably get an array of bytes from your image, but that is not in PNG format. Are you using PIL, Pillow or something else?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `Image` is and where it comes from ?

Comment: I want to save the Image as PNG @NanoPish Sorry, I forgot to mention it

Comment: @LuísCosta updated my answer with an example at saving image object as png with PIL

Comment: @LuísCosta could you accept my answer, if you think it is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What library do you use?

If you want to write a png image file to disk you need to get the formatted data, e.g. with BytesIO:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.new("RGB", (300, 50))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), "This text is drawn on image")

byte_io = BytesIO()

image.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
```

It will be different depending on the library you use.

---

If you want to save a python image object to disk, you can use pickle / serialization.

In case of pure Python classes you can simply use pickle:

```
import pickle
with open('Storage', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(instance001, f)

and load it:

with open('Storage', 'rb') as f:
    instance002 = pickle.load(f)

print(instance002.a)   # 2
print(instance002.b)   # 200
```

---

It looks like you use PIL. You save Image as a PNG file like this:

```
newImg1.save("img1.png","PNG")
```

Comment: This should have stopped at the first sentence, and be in a comment.

Comment: The last line did the trick! Thank you and sorry for a late reply. Dissertation times are hard